# downgrading from 10.7.2 to 10.7.0

Tags: macbook, updates

I have the latest Mac book Air, it was with 10.7.0 installed when I ran it for the first time. After getting updated to 10.7.2 My Autocad 2011 is crashing a lot, I want to revert back to original 10.7? What I need to do that? I dont have any DVD/USB installer, Is there any copy of installer hidden inside macbook air?

Comment: There is Recovery HD: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718 that should be present on your Macbook Air; that lets you reinstall Lion. However I am not sure if it would restore to 10.7.0 (when the recovery HD was created) or to the latest version 10.7.3. Note that the internet recovery also mentioned in that link would most likely do 10.7.3. This said, it is never a good idea to use outdated version of the OS due to security patches that are not applied to it. Perhaps you may want to check the Autodesk tech support or forums about fixing the Autocad issues.

Comment: Maybe it'd really make more sense to check out the crash logs and see why this happens (check *Console.app* for messages).